# Using a MAX, Ignoring a GROUP BY for only 1 column for a DISTINCT COUNT

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with order numbers, units, lines, and skus. I want to do the following:

```
-Distinct count order numbers
-Sum units
-MAX line number (grouped by order number. This can't just be a sum, if an order has 3 lines, it will have 3 rows and summing would give me 6 (1+2+3))
-Distinct count ALL SKUs (the group ordernum by inflates this number. I want to end up with 3 SKUs in the table below. The group by ordernum would give me 4)
```

I will then eventually use a subquery to sum everything up:
-SUM Orders
-SUM Units
-SUM Lines
-SUM SKUs

```
OrderNum    Units   Line    sku  
123456789   1       1       ABC  
988890000   1       1       CCC  
988890000   1       2       DDD  
988890000   1       3       ABC 

SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT(Ordernum)) Orders,
SUM(Units) Units,
MAX(Line) Lines,
COUNT(DISTINCT(Sku)) SKUs
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Ordernum
```

Comment: What value are you expecting for Lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `GROUP BY OrderNum`, you will need to use two separate queries to generate this information. In the SUM() query, you would add a subquery similar to this:

```
WITH DataExtract as (
    SELECT 
        Ordernum,
        SUM(Units) Units,
        MAX(Line) Lines
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY Ordernum
    )
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT orderNum) Orders, 
    SUM(Units) Units,
    Sum(Lines) Lines,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SKU) from MyTable) SKUs
FROM DataExtract
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
CREATE TABLE #Orders
(
    OrderNum VARCHAR(10)
  , Units INT
  , Line INT
  , sku VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO #Orders VALUES ('123456789', 1, 1, 'ABC');
INSERT INTO #Orders VALUES ('988890000', 1, 1, 'CCC');
INSERT INTO #Orders VALUES ('988890000', 1, 2, 'DDD');
INSERT INTO #Orders VALUES ('988890000', 1, 3, 'ABC');

SELECT * FROM #Orders;

SELECT     COUNT(DISTINCT a.OrderNum) AS Orders
         , SUM(a.Units)               AS Units
         , b.Lines
         , b.SKUs
FROM       #Orders AS a
CROSS JOIN (
               SELECT MAX(OrderNumLineSum) AS Lines
                    , MAX(x.SKUCount)      AS SKUs
               FROM   (
                          SELECT   OrderNum
                                 , SUM(Line)  AS OrderNumLineSum
                                 , COUNT(sku) AS SKUCount
                          FROM     #Orders
                          GROUP BY OrderNum
                      ) AS x
           )       AS b
GROUP BY   b.Lines
         , b.SKUs;
```

Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9eac2184f8b8ab2513a79623f54e673b).